# Any opensource alternative to squish to test flash/silverlight/java applet gui objects?

Tags: java, silverlight, flash, testing

If one doesn't have the source code, the only to test is to send keystroke and mouse move so I found this product but it's not free and opensource price is not even known :(

http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/4.1/all/ugs-webnonhtml.html

Squish supports automating interactions and testing non-HTML/DOM elements, that is, native objects, which are embedded in a web page. This is done at a fairly abstract level, which means that mouse and text input can be recorded and replayed. In addition it is possible to inspect embedded native objects with the Spy tool and to insert verifications for these native objects. All of a native object's public properties can be accessed in test scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [Sikuli IDE](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/download.shtml) .

It is more geared for automation than for testing, but it works nice.

Comment: Wow fantastic thanks a lot couldn't see it while googling google sucks :)

Comment: it's great but I can't make it work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251517/functional-test-sikuli-doesnt-work-with-basic-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you are loooking for some open source testing tools for testing different objects, than this page having 106 open source testing tools might by useful for you.
http://www.opensourcetesting.org/functional.php

Comment: well none can do flash testing